# Slick slider progress bar doesn't match number of slides

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, slick.js

I have created a carousel which contains `7` items in total.

This carousel will showcase `5` by default.

In my demo, I'm having two issues:

1. The slider is set to `infinite`, however, the progress bar does not reset when it have gone back to slide 1.
2. Once the slider has reached the end, it just jumps back onto slide 1 (rather than transition smoothly)
3. Once slide 7 (card 7) is in view, then the progress bar should be complete

A `console.log` of `$slider.slick("getSlick").slideCount` returns 7, which is the correct amount of items in the slider. So unsure what is causing these issues.

```js
(function($) {

  const $slider = $('#slider');
  var $progressBar = $('.progressBar__bar');

  $slider.on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    var calc = ((nextSlide) / (slick.slideCount - 1)) * 100;
    $progressBar.css('background-size', calc + '% 100%').attr('aria-valuenow', calc);
  });

  $slider.slick({
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    speed: 400,
    arrows: true,
    mobileFirst: true,
  });


})(jQuery);
```

```css
.cardSlider {
  padding: 100px 0;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.card {
  color: black;
  padding: 50px;
  text-align: center;
}

.progressBar__bar {
  margin-top: 82px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, yellow);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 5% 100%;
  transition: background-size 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.progressBar__bar[aria-valuenow="0"] {
  background-size: 5% 100% !important;
}

.progressBar__bar[aria-valuenow] {
  height: 5px;
}

.progressBar__bar:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 0.5pt;
  background-color: white;
}

.slick-slide {
  margin: 0px 10px;
  display: none;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 1px;
  outline: none !important;
}

.slick-slide.slick-loading {
  display: none;
}

.slick-slide.dragging img {
  pointer-events: none;
}

.slick-slide img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}

.slick-slider {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  touch-action: pan-y;
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

.slick-list {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.slick-list:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.slick-list.dragging {
  cursor: pointer;
  cursor: hand;
}

.slick-track,
.slick-list {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 150ms ease;
}

.slick-track {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.slick-track:before,
.slick-track:after {
  display: table;
  content: "";
}

.slick-track:after {
  clear: both;
}

.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section class="cardSlider">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="cardSlider__listing" id="slider">

          <article class="card">
            Card 1
          </article>

          <article class="card">
            Card 2
          </article>

          <article class="card">
            Card 3
          </article>

          <article class="card">
            Card 4
          </article>

          <article class="card">
            Card 5
          </article>

          <article class="card">
            Card 6
          </article>

          <article class="card">
            Card 7
          </article>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="progressBar">
          <div class="progressBar__bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div> 
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think progress bar is working fine as of now in your code.

For your second point regarding transition smoothly, Please remove below CSS from your code and try.

```
.slick-track,.slick-list {
   transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transition: all 150ms ease; 
}
```

### Update

Please check below changes also. I am also attaching Codepen link over here: https://codepen.io/nandu1993/pen/xxjdZjd

```
.progressBar__bar {
  margin-top: 82px;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, yellow, yellow);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 0% 100%;
  transition: background-size 0.5s ease-in-out;
}



$(document).ready(function () {

  const slider = $('#slider');
  var progressBar = $('.progressBar__bar');
  //for first time load
  slider.on('init', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    currentDot = $(".slick-dots .slick-active").index() + 1;
    dots = slider.find('.slick-dots li').length;
    calc = (currentDot / dots) * 100;
    progressBar.css('background-size', calc + '% 100%').attr('aria-valuenow', calc);
  });

  slider.on('afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    var currentDot = $(".slick-dots .slick-active").index() + 1;
    var dots = slider.find('.slick-dots li').length;
    var calc = (currentDot / dots) * 100;

    progressBar.css('background-size', calc + '% 100%').attr('aria-valuenow', calc);
  });

  slider.slick({
    slidesToShow: 5,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    dots: true,
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: false,
    arrows: true,
    mobileFirst: true,
  });
});
```

Comment: Hi Nandan, the progress bar is not working as intended. For example, if I add "infinite: false" to the slider, and then reach the end of the slider, the progress bar isn't even 50% full. This can be seen in this demo here: https://codepen.io/amit_rai95/pen/qBYrOdB

Comment: @Freddy : Okay. Please check now. And also look at the that codepen link. I hope this is works for you.

Comment: I can see you’ve used `dots: true` to achieve this. Is this the only way? In addition to this, I can see you’ve set the initial progress bar to `background-size: 14.29% 100%;`. If you navigate to the last slide, and then back to the first, you will see that the bar is much larger than `14.29%`. Is there a way to dynamically set the initial background size, based on number of slides?

Comment: Yes. we are counting slide based on dots so we have to use that true. You can hide dots using jquery.  If you use background-size: 5% 100%; as default then there is some mismatch with initial progressbar and when you slide to 2nd slide and again move to slide 1 then progress bar is different.

Comment: I've currently got background size as `0% 100%` in my CSS. The reason I initially had it as `5%` in my original demo was because the slider was set to loop indefinitely. However, I would want the progress bar to fill automatically based on the number of slides, rather than setting it to a % via CSS - does that make sense? It just makes it more dynamic.

Comment: @Freddy Got it. I have made changes in code pen link. Made progress bar to set dynamic progress based on the slides. Please check.
I have made below changes.

`background-size: 0% 100%;`

Added init function after progress bar is defined

`slider.on('init', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {`

Hope this works for you

Comment: Thanks, that looks to have done the trick!

Comment: Also might be worth editing your question and posting the Codepen solution here, incase you delete that pen later down the line, at least the solution still remains here for others :)

Comment: @Freddy I have updated above answer from code-pen.